# Redis hincrby is not providing expected result?

Tags: node.js, redis

I had promisified the redis functions using util.

1)I had set a  value 5 to the balance.

2)i tried to **increment value by 2**, then the **value** is set as **NaN**

3. i **tried** it with **parseint(2)** also, same result is getting
4. when i get the data in hash using hgetall and checked its data type ,**before it is turned to Nan** its **showing as string**

   const myfunc = async() =>{
   var setvalue= await (RedisClient.hmset(['key','balance',5]));
   var incr = await (RedisClient.hincrby('key','balance',2));
   //Nan is assigned when i tried to increment
   var res= await (RedisClient.hgetall('key'));
   console.log(typeof res.balance); // returns string
   }

I don't know what' happening.

Comment: All data in redis is stored as a string, so the `typeof` result is expected. However, as long as the existing string contains a numeric value `hincrby` will work as expected.